# Using MJPG stream as a webcam source

Tags: arch-linux, camera

I would like to use my Android smartphone as a webcam and found the app "IP webcam", which creates various outputs of the camera.

One such output is a MJPG stream, and I want to know if there is a way to get this stream to work as a webcam-source on my Arch Linux

I know there is [Droidcam](http://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linuxx/), but I just can't get it to work on my machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't test this because the app crashes on ICS, but this should be possible using [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) and [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/).

Compile and load the v4l2loopback kernel module. Note down the v4l2 device it creates (`/dev/videoX`).

Then use something like the following:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v souphttpsrc location='http://<your_phones_ip>:<port>/' is-live=true user-id=<user> user-pw=<pass> ! multipartdemux ! decodebin2 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/videoX
```

While the gstreamer pipeline is running, the video should appear in `/dev/videoX` and the device can be used like a normal webcam.

Comment: awesome! Works perfectly. Note for "IP Webcam" users: use `http://ip:port/videofeed` as source.