# How to enable MJPG on a USB Camera (video)?

Tags: camera

I got a camera module over USB, which is supposed to support MJPG format allowing better resolution/framerate than the VYUY default codec.

After several tests on my Debian, I could not make the MJPG format to work: both, using my webbrowser and a test application in OpenCV.

I am starting to consider if Debian does not support it by default, which the following questions seems to corroborate.

[Using MJPG stream as a webcam source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12626/using-mjpg-stream-as-a-webcam-source)

[Saturated blue image in MJPG streaming with a Raspberry Pi and a webcam](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179249/saturated-blue-image-in-mjpg-streaming-with-a-raspberry-pi-and-a-webcam)

My question is:
**How to allows MJPEG codec to be used, or how to ensure it is available and that it is the camera not supporting it?**

Could I ask some explanation on the topic?

Comment: `which is supposed to support MJPG` ... is that a `it supports MJPG` or is it a `i don't know if it supports MJPG`?

Comment: Hi @jsotola, The Documentation about the camera module claim it does.